# Painted JPanel gets flushed every time the window is minimized or dragged out of screen

Tags: java, swing

I am drawing a grid on a JPanel by overriding paint(g) and with it marking some points whichever clicked on the grid, but the main problem is, if someone minimize the grid or drag it around the screen, the part of the screen goes blank. I can't figure out how to change my code to have it refreshed every time the screen is minimized or dragged around, please help me with the code.

Here is my code:-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class draw extends JPanel {

private int x,y,X,Y,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax;
private int clickParam = 0;
private double d, theta;
private ArrayList<Integer> ab = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<Integer> or = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<Double> distance = new ArrayList<Double>();
private ArrayList<Double> angle = new ArrayList<Double>();
Graphics2D g2d = null;

 public void drawing(){

     repaint();

 }
 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

     super.paintComponent(g);
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

     g2d = g2;
     int stroke[]={1,2,3,4,5};

     g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke[1]));
     xmin = 150;
     ymin = 150;
     xmax = 650;
     ymax = 650;
     int xsize = xmax - xmin;
     int ysize = ymax - ymin;
     g2.drawRect(xmin, ymin, xsize, ysize);
     for(int i=50;i<=xsize;i+=50){

        g2.drawLine(xmin+i, ymin, xmin+i, ymax);
        g2.drawLine(xmin, ymin+i, xmax, ymin+i);

        }
     g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke[0]));
     for(int i=10;i<=xsize;i+=10){

        g2.drawLine(xmin+i, ymin, xmin+i, ymax);
        g2.drawLine(xmin, ymin+i, xmax, ymin+i);

        }

 }
 public void drawPoints(Graphics2D g2){

     if(x >= xmin && x <= xmax && y >= ymin && y <= ymax)
            g2.fillOval(x-3, y-3, 7, 7);

 }
 public void onClick(){

     addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

         @Override
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

                setxy(e);
                setXY();               
                clickParam = 2;
                drawPoints(g2d);

                if(x >= xmin && x <= xmax && y >= ymin && y <= ymax){

                    setDistance();
                    setAngle();
                    display();
                }   
             }

     });

 }
 public void setxy(MouseEvent e){

    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    if(x >= xmin && x <= xmax && y >= ymin && y <= ymax){
    ab.add(x);
    or.add(y);
    }  
 }
 public void setXY(){

     X = x - xmin;
     Y = ymax - y;

 }
 public void setDistance(){

     d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(X/10, 2) + Math.pow(Y/10, 2));
     distance.add(d);

 }
 public void setAngle(){

     theta = Math.atan2(Y,X)*180/Math.PI;
     angle.add(theta);

 }
 public void display(){

     System.out.println("(X,Y) = ("+(X/10)+","+(Y/10)+")"+" & (d,theta) = ("+d+","+theta+")");

 }
 }
```

and the main class:-

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainClass {

public static void main(String args[]){
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame("TEST");
    draw d = new draw();
    jframe.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
    jframe.pack();
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.add(d);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
    jframe.setResizable(false);
    d.drawing();
    d.onClick();


}

}
```

Comment: It seems like you are not saving the dots that were already painted on screen. I've done the following test with your code: Started the program, minimized the window, clicked on it from the taskbar.The grid is still displayed on screen. 2nd test: Clicked on screen. A dot is printed. Minimized the window. Pressed on it from the taskbar, now only the dot is printed. Meaning, you need to "remember" the changes that were made and repaint the whole thing.

Comment: yeah that's what i can't figure out, how to remember the changes and repaint them, thanks for replying

Comment: And this app. has a `setxy()` method (that illogically adds a mouse listener) and a `setXY()` method just to confuse the reader! You obviously learned ***nothing*** from my [previous suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39534311/418556), so I won't bother trying to help on this one..

Comment: okay that's my mistake, gonna correct it, but what about repainting the changes, it's pretty urgent

Comment: The `if(clickParam == 0){` part doesn't make any sense, this will cause the grid only to be painted if the user hasn't clicked on the panel yet. Also, override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` and call `super.paintComponent(g)`. Store the points in an `ArrayList`.

Comment: calling super.paintComponent(g) just makes the last painted component visible, all other previous components are lost

Comment: @MohitRai Again, that's because of `if(clickParam == 0){`... Fix that part and store your points in a list...

Comment: @LukasRotter I updated my changes to the class draw above and i am making the call to the function drawPoint() whenever the button is clicked, but now it isn't marking the points with dots, instead only grid is displayed, whats going wrong in here and i updated it as you suggested

Comment: @MohitRai You never call `drawPoints` in your `paintComponent` method now and you added a new method `onClick` which never gets called... Therefore the mouselistener is never added. Would it be OK for you if I'd completely restructure the code and posted the new one as an answer, explaining why I made the changes I did?

Comment: it'd be great thanks, i'm waiting for the reply and hey i'm sorry i forgot to mention the mainClass, now i have updated the code

Comment: Folks pretty amazing it is, I got the solution, what I did is I stored the points in an array list and repainted the whole window (as some of you suggested), this made the graphic to render every time the window minimizes or drags around. Thanks a lot guys, you people are amazing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `onClick` is never called, therefore the `MouseListener` is never added.
2. Create a list of `Point`s and loop through it in your `paintComponent` method.
3. `drawPoints` should only be called inside the `paintComponent` method, since it takes the current `Graphics2D` object.

---

Restructured code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Draw extends JPanel { // Class names should start with an uppercase letter

    private int xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;
    private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>(); // Create a list where all clicked points will be stored

    public Draw() {
        xmin = 150;
        ymin = 150;
        xmax = 650;
        ymax = 650;
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { // Add MouseListener in the constructor
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                Point point = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (point.x >= xmin && point.x <= xmax && point.y >= ymin
                        && point.y <= ymax) {
                    points.add(point); // Add the point to the list
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        int stroke[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke[1]));
        int xsize = xmax - xmin;
        int ysize = ymax - ymin;
        g2.drawRect(xmin, ymin, xsize, ysize);
        for (int i = 50; i <= xsize; i += 50) {
            g2.drawLine(xmin + i, ymin, xmin + i, ymax);
            g2.drawLine(xmin, ymin + i, xmax, ymin + i);

        }
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(stroke[0]));
        for (int i = 10; i <= xsize; i += 10) {
            g2.drawLine(xmin + i, ymin, xmin + i, ymax);
            g2.drawLine(xmin, ymin + i, xmax, ymin + i);

        }
        drawPoints(g2);
    }

    private void drawPoints(Graphics2D g2) {
        for (Point point : points) { // Loop through the list of points
            g2.fillOval(point.x - 3, point.y - 3, 7, 7);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame("TEST");
        Draw d = new Draw();
        jframe.setSize(800,800);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setContentPane(d);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah I did the same thing, but your code is a lot cleaner thanks a lot for the answer, well i got to know the window should be painted every time it goes away from the screen or minimizes, isn't it? thanks again